# Overriding didSelectRowAtIndexPath on a framework-provided view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

So I'm using the CoreAudioKit's [CABTMIDICentralViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1831/_index.html) to present a list of MIDI Bluetooth devices for the user to select. However, I want to be able to tell which device the user selected when they're done, but it doesn't seem Apple has added any way to do that.

So I'm trying to hack it by detecting when the user selects a row in the table:

**DPBleMidiDeviceManager.h:**

```
#import <CoreAudioKit/CoreAudioKit.h>

@interface DPBleMidiDeviceManager : CABTMIDICentralViewController

@end
```

**DPBleMidiDeviceManager.m:**

```
#import "DPBleMidiDeviceManager.h"

@implementation DPBleMidiDeviceManager

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"midi device selected %@", indexPath);

    //either of these next lines crash, it makes no difference:
    //[[tableView delegate] tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [super tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
@end
```

The problem is, it's crashing on the last line saying there's no selector. Which is weird, because if I remove the super call, it doesn't crash, but it also doesn't correctly connect to the BLE device, like it would if I was not overriding that delegate call.

Is this just something Apple does so you can't access their tables? Why would they build a UI view like this and let you call it, but not give you any information about what the result was? Am I missing some standard way to do this?

EDIT: here's the details of the crash with the `super` call:

```
2015-10-29 15:14:37.039 [626:338267] midi device selected <NSIndexPath: 0x1473ae20> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-10-29 15:14:37.039 [626:338267] -[DPBleMidiDeviceManager tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147f34e0
2015-10-29 15:14:37.040 [626:338267] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DPBleMidiDeviceManager tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147f34e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2b3cdfef 0x3967dc8b 0x2b3d3409 0x2b3d11bf 0x2b300e78 0xaa165 0x2eb3956b 0x2ebe843b 0x2ea9da91 0x2ea1838f 0x2b393fed 0x2b3916ab 0x2b391ab3 0x2b2de201 0x2b2de013 0x32aab201 0x2ea82a59 0x88447 0x39c09aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you call super. It should be

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"midi device selected %@", indexPath);

    [super tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: You're right, and I tried both ways. They both crash.

Comment: What's the crash when you use the above?

Comment: Added the crash log to the question. Thanks!

Comment: You are calling super with `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` when you probably mean `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: haha oh wow I am not a smart man. Guess the Xcode autocomplete thought that was a better first choice and I didn't question it. Thanks for the help! It's working now!